# Limit of fetching Server time using firebase function

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to fetch server time on device so I am using FirebaseDatabase builtin function: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/serverTimeOffset")`
I want to know if there is any limit of free usage or number of connections.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/pricing?authuser=0

Comment: @shuabing I am not sure whether the pricing applicable to this builtin function or not.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/pricing show at Cloud Functions
Invocations Item, I think builtin function include in it.